# SQLite C# returns the wrong bytes from the database

Tags: c#, .net, database, sqlite, google-chrome

I'm trying to retrieve the passwords from the Chrome database, it works well when using Python but when using C# I get different bytes.

The python code returns the following when querying the password from the database (The hex values "76 31 30" are the v10 part):

```
0x76 0x31 0x30 0xd2 0x72 0x89 0xc7 0xcf ...
```

The C# code...

```
string passwordColumn = reader.GetString(3); // returns third column
byte[] passBytes= Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(passwordColumn); // get bytes from string
Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(passBytes)); // pretty print
```

...returns the following:

```
76-31-30-EF-BF-BD-72-EF-BF-BD-EF-BF-BD ...
```

Why do every other query I do returns the correct strings, but only when I want the password_value column it just returns the first three bytes correctly?

Funny thing is, when I try to inspect the bytes with this:

```
foreach (int a in passwordColumn) {
    Console.WriteLine(a);
}
```

I get this as output:

```
118
49
48
65533
114
65533
65533
65533
88
114
106
65533
65533
...
```

Only the values that are not 65533 are the correct ones, why is that? Why some bytes are correct but the others are not? And the most important: How to solve this?

Comment: It may have to do with the driver you use. I am not sure. What is the database name, I may be able to give it a shot if I get a chance.

Comment: @NoChance I tried with .NET 5 and .NET Framework 4.7.2, System.Data.SQLite and Microsoft.Data.Sqlite and in every case I got the same result. The database name is "Login Data", which is at "AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Login Data"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Unicode character 65533 (encoded in UTF-8 as EF BF BD) is `�` the [replacement character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)#Replacement_character) used to replace an unknown, unrecognized or unrepresentable character.

It seems that the column's datatype is not TEXT but BLOB, you should use `GetBytes()` instead of `GetString()`

Comment: I stumbled across this GetBytes() method, but I misinterpreted it, I'm sorry for that. Btw thank you for the good explanation.